# Do I need .gitignore in nested subfolders for different projects?

Tags: gitignore

I have a nested project using Angular and Dotnet Web API - I have a gitignore on the root folder in which these two are contained. Do I need gitignores in each? Does gitignore include subfolders? I had some issues with bin and obj and so on but I tried resolving it and it didn't work well - Cleared cache and everything... But I guess it's cest la vie on that workload - but anyway will gitignore be needed in each project folder or can I just set one in the root folder?

Comment: No, You don't need gitignore for each. Gitignore file is per repository, not per project.

Comment: Do you use Git submodules?

Answer (score 0):

> Does gitignore include subfolders?

Yes it does.
Meaning: if you have only one `.gitignore` at the root folder, an entry like obj/ would ignore any folder named `obj` in the root folder or any of its subfolders.

But make sure your folder obj/ was not already tracked:

```
git rm --cached -r project1/obj/
```